# Why does SemiJoin node receive so bad statistic even after runnning ANALYZE

Tags: postgresql, join

PosgtreSQL 9.4

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE home_transactions( id serial NOT NULL, transaction_id integer );
CREATE TABLE transactions( id serial NOT NULL, user_id, amount numeric(13,4) NOT NULL );
```

The tables are relatively small (~100 rows each). Now, I need to select all `(user_id, amount)` pairs for users who have `home_transaction`s. That's a classic usage of `SemiJoin`. But the table has the following statistic:

```
user_id = 959: 92 home trasactions
user_id = 811, 551, 589, 949: 4 home_trasactions
```

so, the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT user_id, amount
FROM transactions t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM home_transactions ht WHERE ht.transaction_id = t.id)
```

produces the following analyzed plan:

```
Hash Semi Join  (cost=3.43..98.26 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.625..0.673 rows=108 loops=1)
                                     ^------EXPECTED                           ^-----ACTUAL             
  Hash Cond: (it.id = bn.internal_transaction_id)
  ->  Seq Scan on transactions t  (cost=0.00..94.40 rows=146 width=12) (actual time=0.554..0.609 rows=146 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=2.08..2.08 rows=108 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=108 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4kB
        ->  Seq Scan on home_trasactions ht  (cost=0.00..2.08 rows=108 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.015 rows=108 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.206 ms
Execution time: 0.710 ms
```

***QUESTION:*** Why is there so different expected and actual rows? I ran `VACUUM ANALYZE` right before the execution but it didn't help. How can I deal with such a distinction?

Comment: Cardinality estimation on the result of a join is always just a guess because Postgres doesn't keep statistics about the correlation of values in different columns (or even tables). Btw: your plan doesn't match with your statement that the tables have ~10k rows - the estimates and actual rows on `transactions` only shows 146 rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, 10K are on the production db.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name fixed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So, in that case, I shouldn't worry about such distinctions, right?

Comment: @St.Antario Right.  The only place when the difference between the estimate and the reality matters are the scans (be it a table or index scan).  A mismatch there suggests stale (or not good enough) statistics.

Comment: @dezso Got it. But don't you know if there's a way to "tell" optimizer that I have some values that are more common than other.

Comment: @St.Antario it's called table statistics, usually working with default settings.  It still does not help to determine the relative cardinality of to separate tables of the same join...

Answer (score -1):

Create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE home_transactions (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    transaction_id integer
);

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    user_id integer,
    amount numeric(13, 4) NOT NULL
);
```

Now, let's analyze the tables and run the query:

```
ANALYZE home_transactions;
ANALYZE transactions;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT user_id, amount
FROM transactions t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM home_transactions ht
    WHERE ht.transaction_id = t.id
);
```